# Not able to access mysql created in private subnet where vpc is having subnet cidr range of 100.0.0.0/26

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, terraform

I've created a VPC and it's having 2 public and 2 private subnets.

The `cidr_range` for public is `[100.0.0.0/26, 100.0.0.64/26]` and for the private is `[100.0.0.128/26, 100.0.0.192/26]`.

Now I created a mysql instance in private subnet which is having a private ip as `10.85.0.2`.

To access the private db, first created the bastion which is having both public and private ip in the same VPC and then created the master instance which is in the private subnet (having only private ip).

Now if I want to access mysql from master then getting error as

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.85.0.2:3306' (110)
```

If I change the `cidr_range` of subnets in the range of `192.168.0.0/26` then I'm able to access the db.

Is there any solution to access db without changing the `cidr_range` `(access in range of 100.0.00/26)`?

Comment: In your question you have IP addresses starting with `100.`, `10.`, `192.`, is it really intended to have all three of them?

Comment: The CIDR 100.0.0.128/26 is not a valid private IP address. That is a valid routable public IP address. Consult RFC 1918 to create valid addressing. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1918 A public IP cannot connect to a private IP without a gateway/proxy.

Comment: Did you check [this GCP docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/private-ip)? Is there any specific reason why you want to use `100.0.0.0/26`, `100.0.0.64/26`? Please check GCP Valid IP Ranges for VPC [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#valid-ranges) as you see valid ranges are: `10.0.0.0/8` `172.16.0.0/12` and `192.168.0.0/16`.

Comment: I'm using cidr_range as 100.0.0.64/26 because all the cidr ranges have been used in another vpc where database is running. So I can't use cidr_range of series 10 or 192 or 172 range.

Comment: The CIDR block 10.0.0.0 is very large (24-bits or 16 million addresses). Normally you can create multiple VPCs from that block.

Answer (score 0):

Writing this as `Community Wiki` for better visibility.

Answer for this question was written by `John Hanley` in the comment section.

> The CIDR 100.0.0.128/26 is not a valid private IP address. That is a valid routable public IP address. Consult RFC 1918 to create valid addressing.datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1918 A public IP cannot connect to a private IP without a gateway/proxy.

In `GCP Documentation - Virtual Private Cloud` you have [Valid Ranges](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#valid-ranges) section which provides your default `Private IP` ranges which are ready to use.

> Private IP addresses [RFC 1918](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918)
>
> 10.0.0.0/8
>
> 172.16.0.0/12
>
> 192.168.0.0/16

That's why you have set CIDR to `192.168.0.0/26` you were able to connect.

Regarding your question:

> Is there any solution to access db without changing the cidr_range (access in range of 100.0.00/26)

IMO, the best solution would be to reconfigure your whole network in your GCP project. Not use `default` VPC but use `custom` and customize VPC to your specific needs